# Pandas Python Lifetime Curves, How to remove outliers from the curves

Tags: python, pandas, lifetime, outliers

I have some lifetime data of subscriptions that shows the % of billings of a week vs the first week the subscription was created. So if there were 1000 subs created and in "Billed Week5" there is still 0.3166 remaining (i.e.316.6 of those billed).

I want to clean out "bad data". Sometimes we don't bill for some weeks due to technical issues and then do catch up billings. this screws up my retention curves when using it for other predictions.

How can I clear out some of those technical error related retention % rates so I don't use them in my model.

I was thinking some logic like. If current value of the retention rate(% difference between column X and column X -1) is a Absolute delta value of 0.20 different to the average of the 3 prior columns then remove the value. i.e. in the last table below, I would want to get rid of values in row 1 column %Billed Week4 and %Billed Week5. I think my rule would kill %Billed Week6 as well(even though the actual rate in the corresponding table of 0.1990 looks fine.

I tried doing a lambda like this but got the error "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable" If I could get that working I could loop through the columns.

```
df['%BilledWeek5']= df['%BilledWeek5'].apply(lambda x: x if (((x['%BilledWeek4'] + x['%BilledWeek3'] + x['%BilledWeek2'])/3)/x-1).abs() <0.2 else '')
```

Maybe I am completely going about this the wrong way. There is probably some statistical functions to use too.

```
import pandas as pd

subscriptionlifetime = [{'Country':'DE','Product':'Cable','Created Week':'cWeek1','Billed Week1':0.2430,'Billed Week2':0.2240,'Billed Week3':0.2207,'Billed Week4':0.0934,
'Billed Week5':0.3166,'Billed Week6':0.1990,'Billed Week7':0.1889,'Billed Week8':0.1816},
         {'Country':'DE','Product':'Cable','Created Week':'cWeek2','Billed Week1':0.2411,'Billed Week2':0.2407,
         'Billed Week3':0.2234,'Billed Week4':0.2222,'Billed Week5':0.0917,'Billed Week6':0.3206,'Billed Week7':0.2006,'Billed Week8':0.1909},
         {'Country':'AU','Product':'Satelite','Created Week':'cWeek1','Billed Week1':0.3019,'Billed Week2':0.2884,
         'Billed Week3':0.2884,'Billed Week4':0.2682,'Billed Week5':0.2657,'Billed Week6':0.1076,'Billed Week7':0.3856,'Billed Week8':0.2403},
         {'Country':'AU','Product':'Satelite','Created Week':'cWeek2','Billed Week1':0.2864,'Billed Week2':0.2748,
         'Billed Week3':0.2623,'Billed Week4':0.2453,'Billed Week5':0.2420,'Billed Week6':0.0963,'Billed Week7':0.3539,'Billed Week8':0.2216}]

df = pd.DataFrame(subscriptionlifetime)

df = df[['Country','Product','Created Week', 'Billed Week1', 'Billed Week2', 'Billed Week3', 'Billed Week4', 'Billed Week5','Billed Week6' , 'Billed Week7', 'Billed Week8']]         

print(df)

  Country   Product Created Week  Billed Week1  Billed Week2  Billed Week3  \
0      DE     Cable       cWeek1        0.2430        0.2240        0.2207   
1      DE     Cable       cWeek2        0.2411        0.2407        0.2234   
2      AU  Satelite       cWeek1        0.3019        0.2884        0.2884   
3      AU  Satelite       cWeek2        0.2864        0.2748        0.2623   

   Billed Week4  Billed Week5  Billed Week6  Billed Week7  Billed Week8  
0        0.0934        0.3166        0.1990        0.1889        0.1816  
1        0.2222        0.0917        0.3206        0.2006        0.1909  
2        0.2682        0.2657        0.1076        0.3856        0.2403  
3        0.2453        0.2420        0.0963        0.3539        0.2216  


for x in range(2,8):

    df['%BilledWeek'+str(x)] = df['Billed Week'+str(x)]/df['Billed Week'+str(x-1)]
    print (x)

print(df)


  Country   Product Created Week  Billed Week1  Billed Week2  Billed Week3  \
0      DE     Cable       cWeek1        0.2430        0.2240        0.2207   
1      DE     Cable       cWeek2        0.2411        0.2407        0.2234   
2      AU  Satelite       cWeek1        0.3019        0.2884        0.2884   
3      AU  Satelite       cWeek2        0.2864        0.2748        0.2623   

   Billed Week4  Billed Week5  Billed Week6  Billed Week7  Billed Week8  \
0        0.0934        0.3166        0.1990        0.1889        0.1816   
1        0.2222        0.0917        0.3206        0.2006        0.1909   
2        0.2682        0.2657        0.1076        0.3856        0.2403   
3        0.2453        0.2420        0.0963        0.3539        0.2216   

   %BilledWeek2  %BilledWeek3  %BilledWeek4  %BilledWeek5  %BilledWeek6  \
0      0.921811      0.985268      0.423199      3.389722      0.628553   
1      0.998341      0.928126      0.994628      0.412691      3.496183   
2      0.955283      1.000000      0.929958      0.990679      0.404968   
3      0.959497      0.954512      0.935189      0.986547      0.397934   

   %BilledWeek7  
0      0.949246  
1      0.625702  
2      3.583643  
3      3.674974
```

Comment: *absolute delta value of 0.20 different to the average of the 3 prior columns* is taking the average of three consecutive columns, subtracting it from the following columns, and then looking for values that stand out. This is called *de-trending* and is a common technique in *outlier detection*. There are many different ways to do it, it's hard to say which one is best in your case. I'd plot the values, try different ways to de-trend, and see what works. This looks like a good start: https://bugra.github.io/work/notes/2014-03-31/outlier-detection-in-time-series-signals-fft-median-filtering/

Comment: Thanks @AleksanderLidtke. I wasn't sure on the terminologies, I will check that page out.

Comment: no worries, hope it works. I've done such stuff before so, if you have any problems or want to discuss something, drop me a message. Section 2.4 of my paper from a few years ago might also be useful (2.3 as well, but it's a bit more involved and application-specific): https://eprints.soton.ac.uk/390088/1/Lidtke.pdf